# How to access Iphone camera in video Mode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to implement video Recording in my IPhone App. How can i access   IPhone camera in Video mode for capturing videos.Plz provide some useful Links.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you want to add `MediaPlayer.framework` then -

Import mediaplayer framework on .h file.

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
```

Delegate this on .h file `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate`

Then create one reference of mediaplayer like this

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
```

Then go in .m file and add this code.

```
-(void)video
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagepicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagepicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagepicker.mediaTypes =[UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:imagepicker.sourceType];
    imagepicker.delegate = self;
    imagepicker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;
    imagepicker.allowsImageEditing=NO;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagepicker animated:YES];
}


- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

    videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

call `video` function as per your requirement and record video and get that video url and data on `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method.

i hope this code useful for you .